# Angular Json response from a Rest API, The response has been truncated

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

The communication with the Api Rest server is fine, it returns code 200. The request used is GET, sending authentication parameters by the header. So far there, the problem is in the content of the response, it shows a partial json and an error message that says: The response has been truncated.

I used the same code with other methods and I had no problem. I infer that the problem is because the json that is returning is very large and truncates it.

**Next the code:**

```
listarConsorcios(): Observable<any> {
        const endpoint = '/api/Consorcios/GetAll';
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token
        });

        return this.http.get(this.urlBase + endpoint, { headers });
    }
```

Comment: Is there any chance of getting the full json despite the size of the json?

Comment: what is the webserver? is it nginx? is it in the development environment

Comment: It is in development environment, localhost for now